# Remove records based on other record values in R

Tags: database, r, record

I have three columns of data: Recipient_ID, Offer_Key, and Response_Code

Whenever an email is sent, a record is generated with Response_Code = 1

Whenever an email bounces, the Response_Code = 2, 3, or 4, depending on the type of bounce.

What I want to do is find the bounced email records, remove the corresponding sent email records for each one(with the same Offer_Key), then remove the bounced email records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
d[!d$Offer_Key %in% unique(d$Offer_Key[d$Response_Code %in% 2:4]),]
```

where `d` is your data.frame.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas!  That works well, except it only filters out a single response_code.  I'd like to filter out any offer_key with a response_code of 2, 3, or 4.